# Using Spring @Validated Annotation to Validate a Get Request Path Variable

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot

I'm trying to use the Spring Validator and @Validated annotation to validate a Get Request parameter but cannot get the validator to run. I'm using a ModelAttribute to try and get the validator to run on the Path Variable instead of the Request Body. Is it possible to run a validator on a Get Request Path Variable?

Here is my controller class and method

```
@RestController
public class ProfileController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/profile/{param}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public IVRProfile getProfile(@Validated(ParamValidator.class) @ModelAttribute("param") String param) {

    return sampleProfile();
    }

    @ModelAttribute("param")
    public String paramAsModelAttribute(@PathVariable String param) {
        return param;
    }

}
```

And the Validator class

```
@Component
public class ParamValidator implements Validator
{

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz)
    {
        System.out.println("Validator supports test");
        return String.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors)
    {
        System.out.println("Validator Test");
        // Validation code

    }

}
```

Neither prints statements are executed when hitting the endpoint.

Any help on what I could be missing or do differently would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can implement desired validation functionality as following.

```
public class ParamValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ParamConstraint, String> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ParamConstraint paramConstraint) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String paramField, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
        //Perform paramField validation
        return true;
    }
}
```

-

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = ParamValidator.class)
@Target( { ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ParamConstraint {

    String message() default "Default validation message";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/profile/{param}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public IVRProfile getProfile(@Valid @ParamConstraint @ModelAttribute("param") String param) {
    return sampleProfile();
}
```

And finally don't forget to annotate Controller with `@Validated`.

```
@RestController
@Validated
public class ProfileController {
    //...
}
```

More details you can find in the example as mentioned [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator).

Comment: this suggestion worked for me from version 1.5.0 of spring upwards

Answer (score 3):

You can create the answer you want by using the fields in the ConstraintViolationException with the following method;

```
    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handlePathVariableError(final ConstraintViolationException exception) {
        log.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);

        final List<SisSubError> subErrors = new ArrayList<>();
        exception.getConstraintViolations().forEach(constraintViolation -> subErrors.add(generateSubError(constraintViolation)));

        final SisError error = generateErrorWithSubErrors(VALIDATION_ERROR, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, subErrors);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

> You need to added an @Validated annotation to Controller class and any validation annotation before path variable field

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get single RequestParams like `status`, you can force it by following the code below.

```
@RestController
public class ProfileController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/profile/{param}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public IVRProfile getProfile(@RequestParam(name = "status", required = true) String status, @ModelAttribute("param") String param) {}

}
```

if you want to force PathVariable, then do this.

```
@RestController
public class ProfileController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/profile/{param}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public IVRProfile getProfile(@PathVariable(name = "param", required = true) String param, @ModelAttribute("param") String param) {}

}
```

Hope this work!!!

Comment: Hi Oyewole. I see I wasn't clear in the post, I meant validating a path variable not request param. I've updated the post to be more consistent. My problem isn't with getting the variable, but running the validator on the variable